# Error in Bluemix Liberty when injecting a simple CDI managed bean into a servlet

Tags: java, runtime-error, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

When injecting a simple CDI managed bean into a servlet (starting from the generated code sample "SimpleServlet"), when accessing the servlet, Bluemix Liberty logs this error :

> "SimpleServlet cannot be injected as class
>   wasdev.sample.servlet.SimpleServlet is not in a bean archive."

This is so even when a beans.xml file with discovery "all" is used.The target looks like this

[image: The target with bean.xml]

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Inject
 private TestService svc;

Answer (score 2):

Reason for Error :

The error is due to not having a beans.xml in the built application war i.e. JavaHelloWorldApp.war

Currently, for performance reasons, the beans.xml file is always required in order to use CDI on Bluemix.

Solution :

Copied the bean.xml inside the /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml then built the code.

This made sure that the bean.xml is packaged into the war file i.e. JavaHelloWorldApp.war and the error is resolved.

Comment: So the problem was that the beans.xml was not in your war?  In the question you stated that the beans.xml was there...

Comment: yes, bean.xml should be there in the war file. I am providing the snapshot below for reference.

Answer (score 0):

To verify bean.xml is deployed correctly to Bluemix, select the java application on Bluemix console, click and open the java application dashboard. Select **Runtime**, select **Files** tab, browse and verify that the bean.xml is deployed correctly inside WEB-INF as shown in the snapshot below.

[image: Bean.xml deployed in Liberty Bluemix]